# How to click on the element using Selenium and VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Html of the element:

```
<div _ngcontent-nxg-c15="" class="box-shadow"><!----><a _ngcontent-nxg-c15="" class="clearfix con-card-voucher text-center ng-star-inserted" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://api.duniagames.co.id/api/product/upload/image/9231439531578882989.jpg&quot;);" href="/top-up/item/freefire"><!----><img _ngcontent-nxg-c15="" alt="Item Logo" class="icon-image style2" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='./assets/images/primary-logo.jpg';" src="https://api.duniagames.co.id/api/product/upload/image/13838880871566571420.jpg"><div _ngcontent-nxg-c15="" class="right style2"><h5 _ngcontent-nxg-c15="" class="title"><b _ngcontent-nxg-c15="">FreeFire</b></h5></div></a><!----></div>
```

The coding I used before was like this, but failed

```
Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("FreeFire")).Click()
```

how to code properly
I use VB.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to induce some *wait* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `FindElementByCss`:

  ```
  Driver.wait 3000 
  Driver.FindElementByCss("div.box-shadow a[href='/top-up/item/freefire'] h5.title>b").Click
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath`:

  ```
  Driver.wait 3000 
  Driver.FindElementByXPath("//h5[@class='title']/b[text()='FreeFire']").Click
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [selenium whatsapp button search vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376971/selenium-whatsapp-button-search-vba/52390082#52390082)

Comment: Thank You Sir @DebanjanB